# How to properly use IO and OptionT in service layer in for-comprehension?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I have a simple repository interface with CRUD operations (probably, it is a bad idea to pass implicit session as parameter in general trait):

```
trait Repository[Entity, PK] {
  def find(pk: PK)(implicit session: DBSession): OptionT[IO, Entity]

  def insert(e: Entity)(implicit session: DBSession): IO[Entity]

  def update(e: Entity)(implicit session: DBSession): IO[Entity]

  def delete(pk: PK)(implicit session: DBSession): IO[Int]

  def findAll()(implicit session: DBSession): IO[List[Entity]]
}
```

And i want to use it like this:

```
for {
  _ <- repository.insert(???)
  _ <- repository.delete(???)
  v <- repository.find(???).value
  _ <- someFunctionReliesOnReturnedValue(v)
} yield (???)
```

Also, i want to stop execution if v is None and rollback transaction if there is any error (i use scalikejdbc). So, as i think, i have to do it in my service layer like this (+ wrap it into Try or something like this to cacth business exception):

```
def logic(???) = {
  DB localTx {
    implicit session => {
      (for {
        _ <- repository.insert(???)
        _ <- repository.delete(???)
        v <- repository.find(???).value
        _ <- someFunctionReliesOnReturnedValue(v)
      } yield (???)).unsafeRunSync() // to rollback transaction if there is any error
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is here: `someFunctionReliesOnReturnedValue(v)`. It can be an arbitrary function which accepts `Entity` not `Option[Entity]`. How can i convert result of `OptionT[IO, Entity]` to `IO[Entity]` and save semantic of `Option[]`?
Is it correct approach or i've mistaken somewhere?

---

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

import cats.data.OptionT
import cats.effect.IO
import scalikejdbc._

import scala.util.Try

case class Entity(id: Long, value: String)

object Entity extends SQLSyntaxSupport[Entity] {
  override def tableName: String = "entity"

  override def columnNames: Seq[String] = Seq("id", "value")

  def apply(g: SyntaxProvider[Entity])(rs: WrappedResultSet): Entity = apply(g.resultName)(rs)

  def apply(r: ResultName[Entity])(rs: WrappedResultSet): Entity =
    Entity(rs.long(r.id), rs.string(r.value))
}

trait Repository[Entity, PK] {
  def find(pk: PK)(implicit session: DBSession): OptionT[IO, Entity]

  def insert(e: Entity)(implicit session: DBSession): IO[Entity]
}

class EntityRepository extends Repository[Entity, Long] {
  private val alias = Entity.syntax("entity")

  override def find(pk: Long)(implicit session: DBSession): OptionT[IO, Entity] = OptionT{
    IO{
      withSQL {
        select(alias.resultAll).from(Entity as alias).where.eq(Entity.column.id, pk)
      }.map(Entity(alias.resultName)(_)).single().apply()
    }
  }

  override def insert(e: Entity)(implicit session: DBSession): IO[Entity] = IO{
    withSQL {
      insertInto(Entity).namedValues(
        Entity.column.id -> e.id,
        Entity.column.value -> e.value,
      )
    }.update().apply()
    e
  }
}

object EntityRepository {
  def apply(): EntityRepository = new EntityRepository()
}

object Util {
  def createFile(value: String): IO[Unit] = IO(Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("path", value)))
}

class Service {
  val repository = EntityRepository()

  def logic(): Either[Throwable, Unit] = Try {
    DB localTx {
      implicit session => {
        val result: IO[Unit] = for {
          _ <- repository.insert(Entity(1, "1"))
          _ <- repository.insert(Entity(2, "2"))
          e <- repository.find(3)
          _ <- Util.createFile(e.value) // error
          //after this step there is possible more steps (another insert or find)
        } yield ()
        result.unsafeRunSync()
      }
    }
  }.toEither
}

object Test extends App {
  ConnectionPool.singleton("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres", "postgres", "")
  val service = new Service()
  service.logic()
}
```

Table:

```
create table entity (id numeric(38), value varchar(255));
```

And i got compile error:

> Error:(69, 13) type mismatch;  found   : cats.effect.IO[Unit] 
>   required: cats.data.OptionT[cats.effect.IO,?]
>             _ <- Util.createFile(e.value)

Comment: There's [liftF](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html#from-optiona-andor-fa-to-optiontf-a). Also, some people would rather prefer returning `IO[Option[Entity]]`, and wrapping it into `OptionT` only in the `for`-comprehension. Could one somehow convert the question into a more [mcve]-like format?

Comment: Oh, sure, i'll convert it. Just wanted to show the basic idea

Comment: You can use Util.createFile(e.value) inside the yield. Or, use _ = Util.createFile(e.value) instead of _ <- Util.createFile(e.value)

Comment: @LalitPrakash, the problem is that after this step may be another step whichrelies on result of file creation (even if there is a unit return type - it's just example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should convert all of your different results to your "most general" type that has a monad. In this case, that means you should use `OptionT[IO, A]` throughout your for-comprehension by converting all of those `IO[Entity]` to `OptionT[IO, Entity]` with `OptionT.liftF`:

```
for {
  _ <- OptionT.liftF(repository.insert(???))
  _ <- OptionT.liftF(repository.delete(???))
  v <- repository.find(???)
  _ <- someFunctionReliesOnReturnedValue(v)
} yield (???)
```

If you had an `Option[A]` you could use `OptionT.fromOption[IO]`. The issues come from trying to mix monads within the same for-comprehension.

This will already stop execution if any of these result in a `None`. As for rolling back the transaction, that depends on how your DB interaction library works, but if it handles exceptions by rolling back, then yes, `unsafeRunSync` will work. If you also want it to roll back by throwing an exception when the result is `None`, you could do something like:

```
val result: OptionT[IO, ...] = ...
result.value.unsafeRunSync().getOrElse(throw new FooException(...))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I got the main idea, but i have a few questions.
Is it a right approach to convert different results type to the most general type explicitly? Or better to use implicit conversion? And is this "ok" to mix different result types in a single for-comprehension as i did in example?
FP approach is new for me, so i try to find out the "best practices"

Comment: Whether to use an implicit conversion is up to your preference. I think the community trend is to use them pretty sparingly as they tend to violate the principle of least astonishment. And mixing different monadic types (IO, OptionT, Future, etc) won't work but mixing their contained result types (Entity, Int, etc) is just fine.